# HtmlUnit android

Tags: android, java

Всем привет. При попытке использовать библиотеку HtmlUnit для парсинга html страницы в моем проекте IDE при компиляции выдает следующее:

```
Android Pre Dex: [htmlunit-2.14-OSGi.jar] trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class": Android Pre Dex: [htmlunit-2.14-OSGi.jar] Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) Android Pre Dex: [htmlunit-2.14-OSGi.jar] when not building a core library. Android Pre Dex: [htmlunit-2.14-OSGi.jar] This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file Android Pre Dex: [htmlunit-2.14-OSGi.jar] in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Android Pre Dex: [htmlunit-2.14-OSGi.jar] Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a Android Pre Dex: [htmlunit-2.14-OSGi.jar] core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's Android Pre Dex: [htmlunit-2.14-OSGi.jar] going on.
```

Значит ли это, что HtmlUnit в android проекте использовать не получится?

Comment: вероятней всего, попробуй jsoup

Comment: к сожалению jsoup не может обрабатывать javascript.